# If m,p,q are integers and $ 1\leq m$, $q \leq m$ then $\frac{m!p}{q}$ is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i'm reading "Principles of mathematical analysis" by Rudin and in the section about sequences and series of functions example 7.4 he say that if m,p,q are integers  $ 1\leq q \leq m$ then $\frac{m!p}{q}$ is an integer, but i don't see why.

Comment: $m!=1\cdot 2\cdot...\cdot q\cdot... \cdot m$ is divisible by $q$

Comment: Assertion false because $q$ can be negative.